# Кнопка обратного действия на JavaScript:

Tags: javascript

Всем привет, есть разметка и `js` код, в разметке `textarea` и 2 кнопки - ***перевод и показать исходный текст***. В `js` коде есть скрипт, который при нажатии на копку ***перевод***, переводит текст. Как сделать так, чтобы при нажатии на кнопку ***показать исходный текст*** всё возвращалось?

```js
const y = document.getElementById('txt1')
const x = document.getElementById('txt1');
const btn = document.querySelector('button');

btn.onclick = () => {
  y.value = x.value.replace(/А/g, 'A').replace(/а/g, 'a').replace(/Ә/g, 'Á').replace(/ә/g, 'á').replace(/Б/g, 'B').replace(/б/g, 'b').replace(/В/g, 'V').replace(/в/g, 'v').replace(/Г/g, 'G').replace(/г/g, 'g').replace(/Ғ/g, 'Ǵ').replace(/ғ/g, 'ǵ').replace(/Д/g, 'D').replace(/д/g, 'd').replace(/Е/g, 'E').replace(/е/g, 'e').replace(/Ж/g, 'J').replace(/ж/g, 'j').replace(/З/g, 'Z').replace(/з/g, 'z').replace(/И/g, 'I').replace(/и/g, 'ı').replace(/Й/g, 'I').replace(/й/g, 'ı').replace(/К/g, 'K').replace(/к/g, 'k').replace(/Қ/g, 'Q').replace(/қ/g, 'q').replace(/Л/g, 'L').replace(/л/g, 'l').replace(/М/g, 'M').replace(/м/g, 'm').replace(/Н/g, 'N').replace(/н/g, 'n').replace(/Ң/g, 'Ń').replace(/ң/g, 'ń').replace(/О/g, 'O').replace(/о/g, 'o').replace(/Ө/g, 'Ó').replace(/ө/g, 'ó').replace(/П/g, 'P').replace(/п/g, 'p').replace(/Р/g, 'R').replace(/р/g, 'r').replace(/С/g, 'S').replace(/с/g, 's').replace(/Т/g, 'T').replace(/т/g, 't').replace(/У/g, 'Ý').replace(/у/g, 'ý').replace(/Ұ/g, 'U').replace(/ұ/g, 'u').replace(/Ү/g, 'Ú').replace(/ү/g, 'ú').replace(/Ф/g, 'F').replace(/ф/g, 'f').replace(/Х/g, 'H').replace(/х/g, 'h').replace(/Һ/g, 'Һ').replace(/һ/g, 'h').replace(/Ц/g, 'Ts').replace(/ц/g, 'ts').replace(/Ч/g, 'Ch').replace(/ч/g, 'ch').replace(/Ш/g, 'Sh').replace(/ш/g, 'sh').replace(/Ы/g, 'Y').replace(/ы/g, 'y').replace(/І/g, 'I').replace(/і/g, 'i').replace(/Э/g, 'E').replace(/э/g, 'e').replace(/Ю/g, 'Iý').replace(/ю/g, 'iý').replace(/Я/g, 'Ia').replace(/я/g, 'ia').replace(/Щ/g, '').replace(/Ь/g, '').replace(/Ъ/g, '').replace(/щ/g, '').replace(/ь/g, '').replace(/ъ/g, '').replace(/ё/g, '').replace(/Ё/g, '');
}
```

```html
<textarea id="txt1" class="txt1"></textarea>
<button onclick="ok()">Перевод</button>
<button>Показать исходный текст</button>
```

Comment: Что  мешает присвоить текст  некой переменной и потом забрать когда будет надо?

Comment: пробовал, не получилось

Answer (score 0):

```js
const y = document.getElementById('txt1')
const x = document.getElementById('txt1');
const btn = document.querySelector('button');
let origin;

function org() {
  y.value = origin;
}

btn.onclick = () => {
  origin = x.value;
  y.value = x.value.replace(/А/g, 'A').replace(/а/g, 'a').replace(/Ә/g, 'Á').replace(/ә/g, 'á').replace(/Б/g, 'B').replace(/б/g, 'b').replace(/В/g, 'V').replace(/в/g, 'v').replace(/Г/g, 'G').replace(/г/g, 'g').replace(/Ғ/g, 'Ǵ').replace(/ғ/g, 'ǵ').replace(/Д/g, 'D').replace(/д/g, 'd').replace(/Е/g, 'E').replace(/е/g, 'e').replace(/Ж/g, 'J').replace(/ж/g, 'j').replace(/З/g, 'Z').replace(/з/g, 'z').replace(/И/g, 'I').replace(/и/g, 'ı').replace(/Й/g, 'I').replace(/й/g, 'ı').replace(/К/g, 'K').replace(/к/g, 'k').replace(/Қ/g, 'Q').replace(/қ/g, 'q').replace(/Л/g, 'L').replace(/л/g, 'l').replace(/М/g, 'M').replace(/м/g, 'm').replace(/Н/g, 'N').replace(/н/g, 'n').replace(/Ң/g, 'Ń').replace(/ң/g, 'ń').replace(/О/g, 'O').replace(/о/g, 'o').replace(/Ө/g, 'Ó').replace(/ө/g, 'ó').replace(/П/g, 'P').replace(/п/g, 'p').replace(/Р/g, 'R').replace(/р/g, 'r').replace(/С/g, 'S').replace(/с/g, 's').replace(/Т/g, 'T').replace(/т/g, 't').replace(/У/g, 'Ý').replace(/у/g, 'ý').replace(/Ұ/g, 'U').replace(/ұ/g, 'u').replace(/Ү/g, 'Ú').replace(/ү/g, 'ú').replace(/Ф/g, 'F').replace(/ф/g, 'f').replace(/Х/g, 'H').replace(/х/g, 'h').replace(/Һ/g, 'Һ').replace(/һ/g, 'h').replace(/Ц/g, 'Ts').replace(/ц/g, 'ts').replace(/Ч/g, 'Ch').replace(/ч/g, 'ch').replace(/Ш/g, 'Sh').replace(/ш/g, 'sh').replace(/Ы/g, 'Y').replace(/ы/g, 'y').replace(/І/g, 'I').replace(/і/g, 'i').replace(/Э/g, 'E').replace(/э/g, 'e').replace(/Ю/g, 'Iý').replace(/ю/g, 'iý').replace(/Я/g, 'Ia').replace(/я/g, 'ia').replace(/Щ/g, '').replace(/Ь/g, '').replace(/Ъ/g, '').replace(/щ/g, '').replace(/ь/g, '').replace(/ъ/g, '').replace(/ё/g, '').replace(/Ё/g, '');
}
```

```html
<textarea id="txt1" class="txt1"></textarea>
<button onclick="ok()">Перевод</button>
<button onclick="org()">Показать исходный текст</button>
```